# Why is SSMS crashing when I edit an agent job step

Tags: .net, ssms

I recently installed SSMS 18.9.2 released a few weeks ago. It's been working fine until two days ago. Now every time I try to edit an agent job step, SSMS crashes with the following information. I have repaired SSMS. Then uninstalled/reboot/installed and it still does this. Short of wiping my computer and reloading EVERYTHING, I'm not sure what to do. I can supply more info on request. Any ideas?

```
Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2019.150.18386.0, time stamp: 0x60e54ecb
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.4300.0, time stamp: 0x5f7e61bb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00021a33
Faulting process id: 0x16e8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d79a7704cee00a
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 304b1f7f-b500-40f5-9399-f8b5e5753acb
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Source: .NET Runtime
Application: Ssms.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 74771A33 (74750000) with exit code 80131506.
```

---

**UPDATE:** So now I'm getting this when trying to use the **DTSWizard.exe** module. Go figure. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after stopping and disabling Cylance AV on my workstation it seems that I no longer get the error and crash when editing a job step or running the DTSWizard.exe module. Don't worry. We are still using Microsoft ATP here.